# Readable HTTPS request and response using Charles Proxy

Tags: proxy, android, http, debug

I am using Charles proxy to see the HTTP request generated through android application. However HTTPS request gets logged in encrypted format.

Is there a way to see HTTPS request & response using Charles for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, this page describes how to configure:

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/

In general it only works if you accept the SSL certificates provided by Charles instead of the original ones.

best,
  carsten